# remove duplication from multi- dimensional array in swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

I have such kind array and I want to remove duplicate values in swift 3.0

> [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2,
>   2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2,
>   2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2],
>   [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [1,
>   1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2], [2, 2,
>   2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]

so what code i have to write for this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately for your question, StackOverflow isn't a freecode service. We can help you to solve some problemes you have in your code, but we won't code for you. If you want someone to code for you, **pay** a developper. Most of us are professionals developpers.

Comment: without code how array is generated ? i got this as result and I tried a lots. ok so please dont make such comment. I already done with swift 4 if you know in swift 3 then write your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code below to filter duplicate arrays and will get in ordered array

```
let filteredArr = Array(NSOrderedSet(array: arr))
```